# Why does the find function return -1 in python when searching a string and failing to find a match?

Tags: python, find

I would expect a return of 0. Is -1 simply the equivalent of false? For a moment I thought it was because 0 is a position (index?) in the string, but so is -1. While I know it is enough to simply memorize that this is how the find operation works, I was wondering if there was a deeper explanation or if this is something common that I will continue to encounter as I study.

Comment: Because `0` is the index of the first character, which would be an extremely unwise thing to return in two separate cases (*found at the start* **and** *didn't find at all*)?

Comment: I never consider `-1` a position, really, just a shorthand for python indexing.

Comment: i think this question is better than it originally appears to be. For the record, 0 is the equivalent of False. bool(-1) returns True

Comment: @jonrsharpe And -1 is the index of the last so that's just choosing between bad and slightly worse.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that is true, but every character in a string has two indices and `find` *always returns the positive one*, so you can check `index >= 0`.

Comment: Also sequence methods from precursor languages like C use `-1` to indicate not found.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That makes perfect sense thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

The objective of the find method is to return the index value, which (for all practical purposes) programmers **want** as positive. In this case, any negative value means that the function could not find the particular element.

The reason why *True* or *False* is **NOT** used is just to avoid thousands of `TypeError`s

Comment: If you only want `True` or `False` then just use `in`.

Answer (score 0):

@jonrsharpe I believe your comment answered my question best. While -1 is an index, the find function always returns a non-negative index when successful and -1 otherwise.